# permission denied trying to download certificate from webstie using openssl, sudo

Tags: linux, sed, sudo

I want to download ssl certificate in my linux server for which I am using this command

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect HOST:PORTNUMBER | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert
```

I need help in using **sudo** for the above command, I tried adding **sudo**  at the start but its failing with permission denied, need help with using **sudo** when using **sed** in command.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need sudo(1) to do this?  Your example works fine for me accessing www.oracle.com:443 like this:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect www.oracle.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

Comment: In my home directory  I don't need sudo , I run  this in my home directory and then use  sudo to   copy over to  required directory.